# ¿Que parámetro se necesita para llamar un DialogFragment? Xamarin Android

Tags: android-fragment, fragment, xamarin.android, diálogo

Tengo 1 Activity, de donde con un botón, llamaré a un dialogfragment, lo que no entiendo es con que parámetro lo llama.

Aquí está mi método del Activity donde llamo al Dialog fragment:

```
public void PopUp()
{
 alert.SetPositiveButton("Actualizar ", (senderAlert, args) =>
                {
                    Bundle linea = new Bundle();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransactions = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                    var myFragment = new Dialog();
                    myFragment.Arguments = linea;
                    myFragment.Show(fragmentTransactions, "dialog fragments");
                    //Update();
                });

                alert.SetNegativeButton("Eliminar", (senderAlert, args) =>
                {

                });

                RunOnUiThread(() =>
                {
                    alert.Show();
                });
}
```

Y aquí está la clase que hereda de DialogFragment:

```
namespace KobitAndroidBeta
{
    public class LineasPopUp : DialogFragment
    {
        View view;
        Spinner spnLineasPopUp;
        EditText txtNombreLineaPopUp, txtDelPopUp, txtAlPopUp, txtIncrementoPopUp;
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.LineasPopUp, container, false);
            return view;
        }
        public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        }
    }
}
```

Quisiera saber como es que lo manda llamar, porque al crear otro DialogFragment, siempre me llama al mismo.

Éste es otro Activity donde llamo al fragmentDialog

```
    private void LstEstilos_ItemLongClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemLongClickEventArgs e)
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

                //list trae el texto que se encuentra en el item de la listview
                var list = e.Parent.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position);
                //Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
                //Región del PopUp
                string parametroBorrado = string.Empty;
                parametroBorrado = list.ToString();

                alert.SetTitle(parametroBorrado);
                alert.SetIcon(Android.Resource.Drawable.StatSysUploadDone);
                alert.SetTitle("Actualizar/Eliminar");

                #region Actualizar ListView
                alert.SetPositiveButton("Actualizar ", (senderAlert, args) =>
                {
                    //Pasar Parámetros al FragmentDialog a partir de la Key o etiqueta del PutString
                    Bundle mybundle = new Bundle();
                    mybundle.PutString("MyDataTag", lstPropiedades[e.Position].IdArticulo.ToString());
                    mybundle.PutString("Color", lstPropiedades[e.Position].Color);
                    mybundle.PutString("Estilo", lstPropiedades[e.Position].Estilo);
                    mybundle.PutString("Del", lstPropiedades[e.Position].Del.ToString());
                    mybundle.PutString("Linea", lstPropiedades[e.Position].Linea);
                    mybundle.PutString("Al", lstPropiedades[e.Position].Al.ToString());
                    mybundle.PutString("Observaciones", lstPropiedades[e.Position].Observaciones);
                    mybundle.PutString("Acabado", lstPropiedades[e.Position].Acabado);
                    mybundle.PutString("Marca", lstPropiedades[e.Position].Marca);
                    mybundle.PutString("Sublinea", lstPropiedades[e.Position].Sublinea);

                    mybundle.PutString("IdAcabado", lstPropiedades[e.Position].IdAcabado.ToString());
                    mybundle.PutString("IdColor", lstPropiedades[e.Position].IdColor.ToString());
                    mybundle.PutString("IdMarca", lstPropiedades[e.Position].IdMarca.ToString());
                    mybundle.PutString("IdTemporada", lstPropiedades[e.Position].IdTemporada.ToString());
                    mybundle.PutString("IdProveedor", lstPropiedades[e.Position].IdProveedor.ToString());
                    mybundle.PutString("IdSublinea", lstPropiedades[e.Position].IdSublinea.ToString());
                    mybundle.PutString("IdClasificacion", lstPropiedades[e.Position].IdClasificacion.ToString());
                    mybundle.PutString("IdLinea", lstPropiedades[e.Position].IdLinea.ToString());

                   /* mybundle.PutString("IniciarProvee", lstPropiedades[e.Position].ToString());
                    mybundle.PutString("IniciarClasi", lstPropiedades[e.Position].ToString());
                    mybundle.PutString("IniciarSubli", lstPropiedades[e.Position].IdSublinea.ToString());
                    mybundle.PutString("IniciarTempo", lstPropiedades[e.Position].ToString());
                    */
//FragmentDialog
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();

                    var myFragment = new Dialog();
                    myFragment.Arguments = mybundle;
                    myFragment.Show(fragmentTransaction, "dialog fragment");
                    lstPropiedades.Clear();
                    LoadEstilo();
                });
                #endregion

                alert.SetNegativeButton("Eliminar", (senderAlert, args) =>
                {
                    //Eliminado lógico del artículo
                    arti.IdAcabado = lstPropiedades[e.Position].IdArticulo;

                    arti.Borrado = true;
                    metodo.UpdateArticuloEstilo(arti);
                });
                RunOnUiThread(() =>
                {
                    alert.Show();
                });
        }
```

Y Aquí su Clase de DialogFragment

```
public class Dialog : DialogFragment
    {
        AltaEstilosController metodos = new AltaEstilosController();
        ListadoDeEstilos le = new ListadoDeEstilos();
        List<Temporada> LstTemporada = new List<Temporada>();
        List<Clasificacion> LstClasificacion = new List<Clasificacion>();
        List<Proveedor> LstProveedor = new List<Proveedor>();
        List<SubLinea> LstSublinea = new List<SubLinea>();
        //Id Del Spinner
        int IdParam = 0;
        int IdColor = 0;
        int IdAcabado = 0;
        int IdMarca = 0;
        int IdTemporada = 0;
        int IdProveedor = 0;
        int IdSublinea = 0;
        int IdClasificacion = 0;
        int IdLinea = 0;
        string Observaciones;
        //Posición del Spinner al iniciar
        int IniciarTempo = 0;
        int IniciarClasi = 0;
        int IniciarProvee = 0;
        int IniciarSubli = 0;
        string subli = string.Empty;

        Spinner spnTemporadaPopUp, spnClasificacionPopUp, spnProveedorPopUp, spnSublineaPopUp;
        EditText txtObservaciones;
        TextView lblColor1, lblEstilo, lblLinea, lblAl, lblMarca, lblDel, lblAcabado;

        Button btnActualiza;
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            //View view;
            base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.DialogInput, container, false);
            btnActualiza = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnActualizarPopUpEstilo);
            lblColor1 = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lblColor1);
            lblEstilo = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lblEstilo1);
            lblLinea = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lblLinea1);
            lblAl = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lblAl1);
            txtObservaciones = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtObservacionesPopUp);
            lblMarca = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lblMarca1);
            lblDel = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lblDel1);
            lblAcabado = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lblAcabado1);
            spnTemporadaPopUp = view.FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spnTemporadaPopUp);
            spnClasificacionPopUp = view.FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spnClasificacionPopUp);
            spnProveedorPopUp = view.FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spnProveedorPopUp);
            spnSublineaPopUp = view.FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spnSublineaPopUp);
            //Recibir parámetros del activity
            IdParam = int.Parse(Arguments.GetString("MyDataTag"));
            string Color = Arguments.GetString("Color");
            string Estilo = Arguments.GetString("Estilo");
            string Linea = Arguments.GetString("Linea");
            string Al = Arguments.GetString("Al");
            Observaciones = Arguments.GetString("Observaciones");
            string Marca = Arguments.GetString("Marca");
            string Del = Arguments.GetString("Del");
            string Acabado = Arguments.GetString("Acabado");
            subli = Arguments.GetString("Sublinea");


            IdColor = int.Parse(Arguments.GetString("IdColor"));
            IdAcabado = int.Parse(Arguments.GetString("IdAcabado"));
            IdMarca = int.Parse(Arguments.GetString("IdMarca"));
            IdTemporada = int.Parse(Arguments.GetString("IdTemporada"));
            IdProveedor = int.Parse(Arguments.GetString("IdProveedor"));
            IdSublinea = int.Parse(Arguments.GetString("IdSublinea"));
            IdClasificacion = int.Parse(Arguments.GetString("IdClasificacion"));
            IdLinea = int.Parse(Arguments.GetString("IdLinea"));

            //IniciarProvee = int.Parse(Arguments.GetString("IniciarProvee"));
            //IniciarClasi = int.Parse(Arguments.GetString("IniciarClasi"));
            //IniciarSubli = int.Parse(Arguments.GetString("IniciarSubli"));
            //IniciarTempo = int.Parse(Arguments.GetString("IniciarTempo"));

            btnActualiza.Click += BtnActualiza_Click;
            spnTemporadaPopUp.ItemSelected += SpnTemporadaPopUp_ItemSelected;
            spnSublineaPopUp.ItemSelected += SpnSublineaPopUp_ItemSelected;
            spnProveedorPopUp.ItemSelected += SpnProveedorPopUp_ItemSelected;
            spnClasificacionPopUp.ItemSelected += SpnClasificacionPopUp_ItemSelected;




            //LOADSPINNER
            #region

            #endregion

            lblColor1.Text = Color;
            lblEstilo.Text = Estilo;
            lblLinea.Text = Linea;
            lblAl.Text = Al;
            txtObservaciones.Text = Observaciones;
            lblMarca.Text = Marca;
            lblDel.Text = Del;
            lblAcabado.Text = Acabado;

            //
            return view;
        }
}
```

Haber si me puedo dar a entender, Tengo 2 Acivity, 2 Clases DialogFragment, pero los dos activity, llaman al mismo DialogFragment, no se como indicarle a cada activity, cual DialogFragment llamar, haber si quedo un poco más claro jeje

Comment: Te lanza algun error? O es que no te muestra el dialogo?

Comment: Me muestra bien todo, pero hice otro DialogFragment, de otro activity, con otro diseño de axml, y otra clase que hereda también de DialogFragment, y cuando lo ejecuto siempre me llama éste DialogFragment, quiero saber cual es el parámetro de llamado

Comment: Donde inicializas el dialog `LineasPopUp`? No lo veo en tu codigo

Comment: No lo inicializé, así lo estoy ejecutando, y de hecho si me abre el DialogFragment, eso está mal?

Comment: He leido tu pregunta varias veces y la logro entender. A que te refires con que llama el mismo `DialogFragment`? Agrega el codigo donde dices que estas llamando un dialog pero te muestra otro.

Comment: Agregue el código del otro DialogFragment, y al final trate de darme a entender mejor, con otra explicación, haber si me di a entender

Comment: La pregunta está editada, haber si se puede entender mejor

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65311/discussion-between-einer-and-oscar-navarro).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a @Einer vi el error

```
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransactions = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                        var myFragment = new Dialog();
                        myFragment.Arguments = mybundle;
                        myFragment.Show(fragmentTransaction, "dialog fragment");
```

Estaba inicializando el Dialog de manera digamos genérica porque lo igualaba a tipo var, era como genérica la "instancia" y por eso me abría el primer DialogFragment que encontraba, tenía que instanciar el DialogFragment en específico que quería que abriera

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransactions = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                        LineasPopUp pop = new LineasPopUp();//El Dialog había que especificarlo
                        pop.Arguments = linea;
                        pop.Show(fragmentTransactions, "dialog fragments");
```